# systeminfo ERROR: not found

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I am new to command line and batch scripting, and I recently bought a book to start learning it.
I am running commands on cmd and they generally work, but there is one that has me stumped: systeminfo.

My machine currently uses Windows 10.
I run cmd with administrator rights and I write:

```
C:\Windows\System32\systeminfo
```

The answer is this:

```
ERROR: not found
```

I tried running this command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\sfc /SCANNOW
```

as I read that some corrupted .dlls may cause some commands not to work properly, but I wasn't able to locate a line saying there was an error, in the log file the Scan program produced. Also nothing changed.

I tried to use my laptop network ip, but it gives me the same error.
The following command actually (almost) works:

```
C:\Windows\System32\systeminfo /s windows
```

and it prompts me to insert a password. I tried inserting my LOCAL ADMIN password, and on another try, my WINDOWS ACCOUNT password/pin
This results in the following error:

```
ERROR: incorrect user name or password
```

Which is impossible, because I changed both passwords to make sure this command worked.
I am at a loss, can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 1):

> My machine currently uses Windows 10. I run cmd with administrator
> rights and I write:
>
> C:\Windows\System32\systeminfo
>
> The answer is this:
>
> ERROR: not found

systeminfo works fine here (Windows 10 Pro). It should work on Windows 10 Home as well.

**(A) Start with DISM and SFC:**

> Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run in order:
>
> dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup
>
> dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image  /restorehealth
>
> SFC /SCANNOW
>
> Let finish, close everything and restart, then test.

**(B) Windows 10 Repair Install:**

If the initial repair commands above do not work, then the next step is a Windows 10 Repair Install.  Begin with the option to Keep Everything.

> Go to the Media Creation Link:
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your suggestion. I tried running the commands you told me but they didn't work. I still get the same errors...

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Repair Install. I amended my answer accordingly.